# Identify which classes have an annotation and get the value of the properties that have an annotation too

Tags: php, symfony, annotations, doctrine

I was reading [this doctrine doc](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-annotations/en/1.10/custom.html#custom-annotation-classes) to use custom annotation in my project but I didn't quite undestand what to do, Im kind of dumb

My original idea was to create a formats maker. Something like writting down some text then some variables surrounded by curly braces and then those with the actual value, I want to let my system know which classes can be used to be formatted and which of its properties can the system use.

Lets suppose, in this image, always retrieve the object with id 1 and that id always exists (forgot to draw it)

[image: example of what I want to do]

What I want to do is to have one or more classes with an annotations and then identify which of the classes have that annotation and let me know which classes they are. In the example from above those available classes should be in the dropdown

```php
/*
 * @Format
*/
public class Pizza {
    public $hasCheese;
    /*
     * @FormatField("pizzaPrice")
    */
    public $price;
```

Lets assume I have a bunch of classes and the only one that has my annotation `Format` and some of its properties have the annotation `FormatField` then I would want to have a way to let me know something like `"It looks like the class Pizza can be used in a Format"` and then which properties are available for formatting, the ones that have `FormatField` and then, somehow retrieve the value of that property through an alias `pizzaPrice`

I wrote this kind of pseudo-code to hopefully better illustrate what I want to learn

```
var availableClasses = getClassesThatHaveFormatAnnotation();
foreach (availableClasses as availableClass) {
    var properties = availableClass.findFormatFields()
    print("Looks like the " + availableClass->name + " class has the Format annotation")
    foreach (properties as property) {
        print("Field available: " + property.name)
        print("Value: " + property.value)
    }
}
```

```
var pizza = findPizzaById(1);
```

Having this pizza I want to be able to access only the properties that have @FormatField above them through its alias, like {{pizzaPrice}} but {{hasCheese}} should not work because it doesnt have @FormatField annotation;

Comment: Did you try to follow the guide at the doctrine website you linked? It is pretty comprehensive on how to add custom annotations and how to parse them. If you have any specific questions when implementing you should update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of a code that finds entities and their annotated properties. You can put the result somewhere. But without replacing the annotated entity you will be available all properties, so maybe you need to create a listener, which will listen to symfony kernel event and modify your response data.

```
    $annotationReader = new \Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader();

    $entities = [];
    foreach ($entities as $entity) {
        $reflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass($entity);
        if (empty($annotationReader->getClassAnnotation($reflectionClass, CustomAnnotation::class))) {
            continue;
        }

        foreach ($reflectionClass->getProperties() as $property) {
            if (empty($annotationReader->getPropertyAnnotation($property, CustomPropertyAnnotation::class))) {
                continue;
            }

            $propertyName = $property->getName();
            $propertyValue = $property->getValue($entity);
        }
    }
```